# How to open 'Add Payment Method' device settings from within a native iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to provide users of my iOS app convenient access to changing their Apple ID payment method, by tapping an in-app button that opens device Settings -> Apple ID -> Payment and Shipping -> Add Payment Method.

Is it possible to program this functionality into a native iOS app? If so, where do I get started?

Comment: You can't open any preferences screen other than your own app's preferences

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
    if let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/account/billing"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
```

Comment: This opens the device access settings for my iOS application. How would I open the Add Payment Method screen?